# Robot Framework using python - how to do backspace in telnet

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, telnet, robotframework

I am trying to execute a command in telnet where at one point when we give enter in the prompt some command is automatically typed after retreiving the output.So if i have to enter the next command i have to press backspace , erase the command that is typed already and then type my new command.I just want to know is there any way i could perform this backspace in robot.I have already tried appending "\x1b[50D" like which was mentioned in docs.But it doesnt work.I think we have to install pyte for that.Anyway, Is there anything else i could do to perform this in robot framework.I also used like below to erase the contents in the lines:

```
Write Control Character    EL
```

But this is also not working.Can anyone please help me out